# CentOS Stream 9 image has predictable interface naming disabled

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, centos, rhel

I'm using a qcow2 image from [here](https://cloud.centos.org/centos/9-stream/x86_64/images/).

Note the net.ifnames=0

```
cat /proc/cmdline

BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-366.el9.x86_64 root=UUID=<uuid> ro console=ttyS0,115200n8 no_timer_check net.ifnames=0 crashkernel=1G-4G:192M,4G-64G:256M,64G-:512M
```

I'm seeing the same thing with a RHEL qcow2 image. I thought modern distributions had predictable interface naming enabled by default? Even in the RHEL [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/consistent-network-interface-device-naming_configuring-and-managing-networking): *"Generally, Red Hat does not support systems where consistent device naming is disabled."*

I've tried several CentOS and RHEL qcow2 images and see net.ifnames=0 for all of them. Is this expected? Is there a way for me to get an image with this enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected and is very typical for cloud images, since you don't have the sort of issues around changing sets of PCI/etc cards that you do in a hardware environment.

> Is there a way for me to get an image with this enabled?

You can...

- Just customize the image: you can mount it on your host using `virt-customize`, `guestfish`, etc and modify the Grub configuration.
- Update the setting as part of your deployment process and reboot (e.g., using a cloud-init script if you're booting in a typical cloud environment).